# asp.net Master Pages and render blocking scripts

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, seo, rendering

I know that SEO related questions must not be asked here but what I want to ask is about the code that affects SEO.

Google Analytics suggests to move render blocking scripts (like jquery) to the bottom of the page. it is easy in pages without master page. but the problem is with pages with master page (that master page itself needs jquery).

If I place the scripts at the bottom of the master page, it is still considered as render blocking as it is called before the page, If I put it at the end of the page (i.e. default.aspx),

1.I should write it in each single page (that in master page i just called it once)

2.I need to call it in pages that don't need jquery just to fulfill master page need

can anybody help me to understand where to call these scripts that neither they block rendering and nor I need to include them where they are not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I cannot understand why you believe a Master page needs jQuery? A Master page is compiled server side and jQuery is a client library.

That said, you can put the code in the bottom of the page to include your scripts, just make sure you have code to resolve the path names.

You can have more than one Master page so have a master page that includes jQuery and one that doesn't.

Comment: menus that uses jquery and are in master page, makes master page need jquery right?

Comment: A Master page that renders and uses jQuery, is no different from a standalone ASP.NET page that renders and uses jQuery on the client. A master page simply allows you to reuse a layout, menus, etc easily across many pages. There should be nothing stopping a Master page from generating HTML page source, which can then be rendered by the browser. You can use various methods in ASP.NET to render script tags and script blocks in various places in your page, the only difference between a Master and a standard page is the master is reusable and so make sure you deal with the paths correctly.